# Partial rendering of an ASP.NET site

Tags: asp.net, iframe, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have an **ASP.NET application** which calls **aspx-pages** in **other ASP.NET applications** (all on the same server and the same solution). This aspx-pages should be shown in a (fixed) region on the main-site in that way that that only the embedded pages is renewed, during user interactions there. Is an IFRAME the only way to achieve this goal, or can I use for example the **AJAX update-panel** or are there further possibilities / techniques. I have read something about the a control "UFRAME". Maybe this is the solution for my question !?!?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display a page within another page, you'll need to use frames or an i-frame. If you have access to all the code for these other ASPX pages though, it would probably be better to use User Controls (ASCX files) instead. You can then easily re-use these in as many pages as you like.